# Selenium or Availability Tests show in pageView?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, azure-log-analytics

I am trying to report on traffic generated by a synthetic agent.

First, should Application Insights Availability Tests generate telemetry in the pageView table?

Second, would Selenium tests? We have some automated QA running on Selenium, I am not seeing it though?

Thanks,
Devin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application Insights Availability Tests are synthetics tests, don't run JS and don't generate PageView telemetry. They generate Availability telemetry which can be alerted/viewed on Availability UX, etc.

Re: Selenium. You're testing web app onboarded on Application Insights JS SDK; On regular visit you see PageViews, but you don't see ones from Selenium tests, correct? Currently JS SDK relies on a few APIs such access to DOM which might not be available in Selenium driver.

Re: report on traffic - for Availability tests you can check Availability telemetry item. For Selenium - if after each execution you can call trackAvailability yourself then this will cover report on traffic for Selenium part as well.

Comment: Quick follow up to question 1) does it matter if its a URL-Ping Test or a Multi-Step? They both do not run JS?

Comment: Yes, they're both synthetic. The latter allows you to simulate a flow - go to auth service, present credential, get token back, parse it, go to another backend, then go to another backend, validate that everything is expected.